# Difference between dap and dip (and inner paragraph)

Tags: object-motions

I have memorized `dip` as the command to delete a paragraph. However, I now see that `dap` is also a thing.

The docs say:

```
"dip"   delete inner paragraph
"dap"   delete a paragraph
```

When I try the two commands, the difference is not *immediately* obvious. I tried searching the docs for "inner paragraph" and I didn't notice anything.

When would I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `dip` delete the inner paragraph (not the blank lines following the paragraph).

The second `dap` delete all the paragraph (including the blank lines following the paragraph if any).

My preference for paragraph is `dap` to avoid to have twice the blank lines between the paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

> I have memorized `dip` as the command to delete a paragraph.

That is not how it works. `dip` is not a thing to remember and `dap` is not one either. `dip` is really the operator `d` (for "delete"), followed by the motion `ip` (for "inner paragraph"). The things worth remembering, here, are:

- the grammatical rule "operator + motion", which governs both `dip` and `dap`,
- the notion of "operator", `d`, here, but there are many others,
- the notion of "motion", `ip` and `ap`, here, but there are *many* others.

Suppose there are 10 operators and 10 motions. If you take the "rote" road, the number of combinations to memorize, like `dip`, `dap`, etc. is 100. If you take the "language" road, that's only 21: the grammar rule and the 20 "words". Guess which strategy is the most efficient?

Now…

> When would I prefer one over the other?

`ap` includes surrounding empty lines while `ip` ignores them. They cover different portions of text so you would choose which one to use based on the desired outcome and, more likely, on what you intuitively consider to be "a paragraph":

- if you only care about the content of the paragraph, use `ip`,
- if you care about the surrounding empty lines, use `ap`.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl. I agree with what you are saying in principle. In practice as a beginner, I found that memorizing a few _common_ actions, the actions that I need on a daily basis, has been a great aid to memorizing the individual operators and motions that form those actions. Thanks for the reminder!